# Replace variable in array using random - generated function. as3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

in as3 I have the following code:

```
var index1
var index2
var num1, num2, num3;
num1 = 1;
num2 = 1;


var nombres:Array =  new Array(
"Ana", "Pedro", "María", "Lily", "Juan", "Rita", "Gonzalo", "Fernanda"
);

var ejercicios_Suma: Array = new Array(
num1+", "+num2+" name:"+nombres[1]
);


dialog();
function dialog (){
num1 = 25
num2 = 26

trace ("********** "+num1+"***** "+num2)    
trace (ejercicios_Suma[0])
}
```

I can't figure how to call the "num1" generated in dialog function, as the variable is replaced by the one outside the code.

Any pointers / solutions?

Thanks in advance.

----- Edited below, to explain problem better ----

As it is right now, the trace result is:
    ********* 25**** 26
    1, 1 name:Pedro

What I need is to have the following:
    ********* 25**** 26
    25, 26 name:Pedro <--- those are the values generated in dialog fucntion, instead of the ones declared outside of the function.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean, can you please rephrase?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to trace num1 and num2 in the ejercicios_Suma[0] array.

Curently, it prints:

********** 25***** 26
1, 1 name:Pedro


but I need to print

********** 25***** 26
25, 26 name:Pedro


instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line,

`var ejercicios_Suma: Array = new Array(num1 + ", " + num2 + " name:" + nombres[1]);`

You're creating an array with only one element, a string with the value `(num1 + ", " + num2 + " name:" + nombres[1])`. At the time when that string is being created, num1 and num2 are equal to 1. So, the array is equal to exactly `["1, 1, name:Pedro"]`.

Even if you go back and edit num1 and num2, the string that was created in that Array won't be updated.

I can't tell at all what you're trying to accomplish w/ this code, so it's hard to say how to fix the code. But, that should explain why you're seeing what you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you Scott, your explanation makes sense. 

I want to update an array with a random generated number (just when the user asks for that function, and the element might repeat itself, but with different values). 

I have several strings in the array, (that I didn't copied in the original post) that need to take those random values. The element of the array is selected randomly too.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Scott, just moved out the array creation after making the random selection, it's working correctly now.